# How would one plot a multivariable function over several disjoint domains?

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot Scherk's first surface which is defined on a checkerboard of the plane, e.g. $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2} < y < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} < y < \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

The patch is $\mathbf{X}(u,v) = (u,v,f(u,v))$ where $f = \ln\left( \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(y)}\right)$.

Comment: Consider plotting the implicit equation for Scherk's minimal surface instead: `ContourPlot3D[Exp[z] Cos[y] == Cos[x], {x, -π/2, 3 π/2}, {y, -π/2, 3 π/2}, {z, -π/2, 3 π/2}]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `RegionFunction` to set the region:

```
Plot3D[Log[Cos[x]/Cos[y]], {x, -(π/2), 3 π/2}, {y, -(π/2),3 π/2}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, -(π/2) < x < π/2 && -(π/2) < y < π/2 || π/
      2 < x < (3 π)/2 && π/2 < y < (3 π)/2]]
```

[image]

Or you can construct the region and plot inside it:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[-(π/2) < x < π/2 && -(π/2) < y < π/2 
      || π/2 < x < (3 π)/2 && π/2 < y < (3 π)/2, {x, y}];
Plot3D[Log[Cos[x]/Cos[y]], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

Comment: Or, `reg = RegionUnion[Cuboid[-Pi/2 {1, 1}, Pi/2 {1, 1}], 
 Cuboid[Pi/2 {1, 1}, 3 Pi/2 {1, 1}]]`.